# How can i make sure that every time i press a button in my kivy app a page gets run again

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, multipage

The code below is one of the pages of my app. The file usernames.txt gets updated with the name of the account whose button I have clicked. The problem is that get user_dates() function gets activated as soon as I run the code. So it gets the username I signed in with the last time and hence it gets the wrong dates. How can i make sure that as soon as I enter my account this page reloads again and user_dates() gets the updated username so that it gets into correct folder and picks up the right dates?

```
class DatesPage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DatesPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.all_dates, self.username = self.get_user_dates()
        print(self.username)
        self.dates_dict = {}
        self.butt_height = 0.7
        for x in range(len(self.all_dates)):
            self.dates_dict[x] = Button(text=self.all_dates[x], size_hint=(0.2, 0.1),
            pos_hint={'x':0.15, 'y':self.butt_height})
            self.add_widget(self.dates_dict[x])
            self.butt_height -= 0.1
    def get_user_dates(self):
        with open('.\\req files\\usernames.txt', 'r') as file:
            username = file.read()
        for root, folders, files in os.walk(f'.\\req files\\{username}'):
            files = files
        files = [re.sub('.txt', '', file) for file in files]
        return files, username
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understood your question, but I think what you want is get an updated page each time you enter the account page, thus call the user_dates() method only when you enter my account.

Well if that is what you trying to do, I think the problem with your code is that you are placing all that code inside the **init** method of DatesPage class, and because kivy initializes all the  **init** methods of all it's widgets when it starts that causes your code here to be run automatically when kivy starts.

If that is not what you want, then you should place your code  in a method other than the **init** method, and bind an event, or button event, to the callback of that method.

So when you press that button to enter my account the binded  event callback will run that method and excecute the code here, and thus my account page will get updated when you open it.